# Position of a delete prompt?

Tags: confirmation, alerts, delete, prompt

In our software, we have a delete prompt where the user has to confirm a deletion. What is the better approach to show the prompt?

1. Centered in the window:

[image]

2. In the near of the pressed button:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How critical/catastrophic would this operation be?

1. Trivial: no prompt needed; rather, provide a simple undo button.
2. Non critical or easily undone: prompt near the button, as to not annoy users too much and make them lose focus.
3. Critical and can't be undone: centered in the page

Comment: thank you for your patience. Do you have a valid source for your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Allowing the user to confirm or cancel the deletion more closely to the Delete button provides better context, and a faster interaction.

Fitts’s Law is a good reference for this question. Fitts’s Law “predicts that the time required to rapidly move to a target area is a function of the ratio between the distance to the target and the width of the target.”

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law